# lim n tends to infinity, $\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} }{(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus

I am interested in the limit $\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} }{(n+1)}$ as n grows without bound. There is already one question on this site asking about this limit. However this is not duplicate, since my question is rather specific.

I understand the standard way of solving it by dividing the fraction by n. But my first thought on how to solve the problem was replace n+1 by n (difference becomes negligible as n grows) and simplify. Is this a valid approach of computing the limit?

Comment: The difference $(n+1) - n$ is always $1$.

Comment: Yeah I know but, proportionally speaking, 2 is twice as much as 1, 54 is proportionally very close to 55.

Comment: Yes, when calculating such limits of algebraic functions as $n\rightarrow \infty$, you can forget about all but the leading terms of any polynomials.  By which I mean you will get the correct answer.

Comment: By leading term of a polynomial, you mean the term with the highest power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\frac{n+1}{n}\rightarrow 1$ is the reason why in rough working to guess the limit you can "replace $n+1$ by $n$", but there's no formal rule that allows straight up replacement of $n+1$ by $n$ while leaving the other $n$ alone.

Comment: Sure there is. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = L$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n+1) = L$.

Comment: @martycohen: I think the OP meant replace the $n+1$s by $n$ but leave the lone $n$ as it is, in which case it's not a direct substitution.

Comment: It seems to be more of the case of ignoring everything but the leading term of the polynomial. Then again, there are those pesky square roots, so we are not dealing with a polynomial. :-(

Comment: Edited to be completely precise, though I thought it was obvious what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can write: $$\frac{\sqrt n \sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}$$

If you desire a division by $n$ :
$$\frac n{n+1}=\frac{\frac nn}{\frac nn + \frac 1n}=\frac{1}{1+ \frac 1n}$$

Comment: That´s quite neat.